# Can I wrap a FilterOutputStream with another FilterOutputStream?

Tags: java, casting, io, stream

I am looking to use two different filters on an output stream. Assume following are the filters.

```
public class FilterStream1 extends FilterOutputStream {
}

public class FilterStream2 extends FilterOutputStream {
}
```

I have an OutputStream out which is currently wrapped using FilterStream1 as below

```
return new FilterStream1(out);
```

Can I modify this to do the following with the addition of the second filter output stream?

```
OutputStream intermediateStream = new FilterStream2(out);
return new FilterStream1(intermediateStream);
```

Is there anything I should keep in mind in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, putting filter streams inside other filter streams is perfectly legal. No problems on the horizon.

In fact, this is exactly the use-case for the decorator pattern which has been implemented in the stream api. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern for reference.)